# Enable Suggestions after dot (.) operator?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

How do I enable suggestions after dot operator in Intellij 14?

For eg., If I have the following code,

### String s = "hello"; --> line 1

### s. ---> line 2

In line 2, If I enter . after the variable 's', the suggestions like variables and methods in class String is not shown in suggestions. How can I enable it in Intellij 14?

P.S : Java class path is set correctly and compilation happens properly. Just the development is screwing me up without showing suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

From IntelliJ, try Help > Find Action..., and then type 'code completion'. Make sure the feature is enabled in Settings.

Comment: There is no option to enable the stuffs posted in the q/s.